# Externally Define Preprocessor Macros in GLSL

Tags: opengl, preprocessor, glsl

GLSL has a full C-style preprocessor. The only thing that does not work is #include. One of the great features is that that you can used #ifdef to comment out functions and thus create one shader that can be thinned out if certain features are not used.

My Question is:

**Is there a way to define a macro from C code?**

There seems no way to do that with the openGL interface. The quick hack is to prepend a few lines with #define FOO before the code loaded form file. But it seems kind of backwards.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't really need to prepend it to the code you loaded. That's why there are multiple strings in the glShaderSourceARB API.

Something like the following does what you are looking for:

```
char *sources[2] = { "#define FOO\n", sourceFromFile };
glShaderSourceARB(shader, 2, sources, NULL);
```

Comment: This is a valid solution, but not much better than prepending the source code.

Comment: well, it depends on what you're after. This is good to prevent some additional memory allocation and copy (which is why I would consider the prepend solution hacky). What would look better to you, and why ?

Comment: I thought more along the lines `glDefine("Moo", "Foo")`... but it seems I studied the specs properly...

Comment: -1: For being a *terrible idea*. The first thing in your shader needs to be a `#version` declaration. By prepending stuff arbitrarily like this, you make that impossible. So you will default to GLSL version 1.10, which is pretty ancient.

Comment: @NicolBolas It's sufficient a `sources[3]== {"#version 330 core\n", "#define FOO\n, ..."`to make it a _good idea_.

Comment: @Luca: Unless of course you have the innovative idea of using a different version of GLSL. Then you have to change it in your code, rather than your shaders. Which means your shaders can't be standalone anymore.

Comment: @NicolBolas What do you suggest is a good solution to create an ubershader then?

Comment: @JustinMeiners: `#define`s don't build ubershaders. The whole point of `#define`s is so that you can build multiple different programs from the same source code. Ubershaders are all about using uniforms to switch features on and off, so that you only infrequently change the bound program.

Comment: @NicolBolas I understand how it could be done with uniforms, but I thought a big advantage came from using the pre-processor to build multiple versions and therefore avoid frequent branching. Is this almost never a good idea? I trust your judgment on this.

Comment: @NicolBolas: this is a perfectly valid solution for uses cases where tight coupling between c and glsl just is not a problem. Often this is even desired: You can share constants/defines between c and glsl that way. Consider array lengths for example.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I use to avoid `#version` problems. It is Java, and not optimized for perfo, but it works perfectly:

```
// extract shader sourcecode from file
StringBuilder shaderSource = Tools.readTextRessource(shaderSrcFile.url);

// apply defined values
int versionIndex = shaderSource.indexOf("#version");
if(versionIndex == -1) err("missing #version xxx in shader "+shaderSrcFile.name());
int defineInsertPoint = shaderSource.indexOf("\n", versionIndex)+1;

for (int i = defined.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    shaderSource.insert(defineInsertPoint, "#define " + defined.get(i) + "\n");
```